# Recording input on buttons and time between presses

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, button

I have a complicated ajax/php problem:

I have 4 buttons. Every time you press a button it records that press to a text file, represented by a string. Let's call the string

```
foo1
```

So, if I had 4 buttons, and pressed the first one 3 times and the second one 2 times it would write this to the text file:

```
foo1;foo1;foo1;foo2;foo2
```

This is where it gets a bit more complicated. If I were to time each press, than the time in between each press would be recorded in [milliseconds] and written to the text file as well in a similar syntax.

I don't where specifically to start trying to figure this whole thing out. Some direction would be lovely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an useful link:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Logging-With-PHP/1/

you can use the microtime() func